# Page loaded with WebDriver Sampler not getting cookies from document.cookie

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

My sampler starts by performing a form post submission through button `buttonAccept` to accept cookies policy. After that it will get another page that loads a javascript frontend, which checks for a cookie in `document.cookie`. Everything works fine manual testing in Chrome. Yet, running the following script in Jmeter, the end page with javascript frontend does not get the previous cookie:

```js
WDS.browser.get('http://localhost:3000');
accept = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.id('buttonAccept'))
accept.click() // Post/Redirect/Get and I see a further GET completed
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart();
WDS.browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/page'); // This page JS does not find the cookie in document.cookie
```

What am I missing?

My test includes the Cookie Manager with standard cookie policy:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why I am experiencing a different behavior running the same test in Chrome or Chrome Driver.

Yet, I solved my issue by replacing the form post submission with an AJAX request. In this case now I am using the native `fetch` function. And then, after that I can get the cookie in `document.cookie`.

I am not aware of any difference on cookies set in response of a form HTTP request or AJAX request, as I can observe in Chrome. Yet, apparently Chrome Driver does not work in the same way.